# It is possible to make dynamic html from json ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, ionic4

I want to make dynamic html from JSON response coming from server,

For eg: Let say json response from server is

```
   param_data: any = {

     "fields": [
     { "type": "text", "name": "firstname", "label": "label", "required": true, "data": "", "frmctrlnm": "labelone" },    
     { "type": "button", "name": "firstname", "label": "label two", "required": true, "data": "", "frmctrlnm": "labeltwo" },    
     { "type": "input", "name": "Red", "label": "input", "required": true, "data": "", "frmctrlnm": "inputone" },  
     { "type": "input", "name": "BLue", "label": "input", "required": true, "data": "", "frmctrlnm": "inputone" },    
     { "type": "label", "name": "color_id", "label": "input two", "required": true, "data": "", "frmctrlnm": "inputtwo" },    
     { "type": "select", "name": "select", "label": "select", "required": true, "data": "", "frmctrlnm": "select" }

     ]}
```

Based on type coming from server i wants to make html component and on click of submit i want same json with user updated data in the fields.

It is possible to achieve this ?

***Thank you in advance!***

Comment: Yes. This can be done. Please show how do u want to display the html

Comment: based on 'type' key i wants to make

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
let htmlString = ``;

param_data.fields.forEach(element => {
  if (element.type == "text") {
    htmlString +=
      `<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4">
          ${element.label}:
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="${element.name}" ${element.required == true? 'required':''}>
        </div>
      </div>`
  }
});
```